# VBA Counter to increment subject lines by 1

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to create a macro which will save out all emails of a selected folder within outlook2010 to my desktop, the code below exports the emails to a specified location but any emails that have the same subject/timestamp are overwritten.

Can I get some advice on how to resolve this issue please.

```
Option Explicit
   Dim StrSavePath     As String

Sub SaveAllEmails_ProcessAllSubFolders()

    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim n               As Long
    Dim StrSubject      As String
    Dim StrName         As String
    Dim StrFile         As String
    Dim StrReceived     As String
    Dim StrFolder       As String
    Dim StrSaveFolder   As String
    Dim StrFolderPath   As String
    Dim iNameSpace      As NameSpace
    Dim myOlApp         As Outlook.Application
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
    Dim mItem           As MailItem
    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim ChosenFolder    As Object
    Dim Folders         As New Collection
    Dim EntryID         As New Collection
    Dim StoreID         As New Collection

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set iNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ChosenFolder = iNameSpace.PickFolder
    If ChosenFolder Is Nothing Then
GoTo ExitSub:
    End If

BrowseForFolder StrSavePath

    Call GetFolder(Folders, EntryID, StoreID, ChosenFolder)

For i = 1 To Folders.Count
    StrFolder = StripIllegalChar(Folders(i))
    n = InStr(3, StrFolder, "\") + 1
    StrFolder = Mid(StrFolder, n, 256)
    StrFolderPath = StrSavePath & "\" & StrFolder & "\"
    StrSaveFolder = Left(StrFolderPath, Len(StrFolderPath) - 1) & "\"
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(StrFolderPath) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (StrFolderPath)
    End If

    Set SubFolder = myOlApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
    On Error Resume Next
    For j = 1 To SubFolder.Items.Count
        Set mItem = SubFolder.Items(j)
        StrReceived = Format(mItem.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD-hhmmss")
        StrSubject = mItem.Subject
        StrName = StripIllegalChar(StrSubject)
        StrFile = StrSaveFolder & StrReceived & "_" & StrName & ".msg"
        StrFile = Left(StrFile, 256)
        mItem.SaveAs StrFile, 3
    Next j
    On Error GoTo 0
 Next i

ExitSub:

End Sub

Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
    Dim RegX            As Object

    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
RegX.IgnoreCase = True
RegX.Global = True

StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")

ExitFunction:
Set RegX = Nothing

End Function


Sub GetFolder(Folders As Collection, EntryID As Collection, StoreID As Collection, Fld As MAPIFolder)
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder

Folders.Add Fld.FolderPath
EntryID.Add Fld.EntryID
StoreID.Add Fld.StoreID
For Each SubFolder In Fld.Folders
    GetFolder Folders, EntryID, StoreID, SubFolder
Next SubFolder

ExitSub:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing

End Sub


Function BrowseForFolder(StrSavePath As String, Optional OpenAt As String) As String
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder '  As Folder

Dim enviro
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, enviro & "\Desktop\")
StrSavePath = objFolder.self.Path

    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0

ExitFunction:
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try function

```
Function FileExists(file as String) as Boolean
    If Not Dir(file, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

This way you can loop and add a suffix to the filename

```
[your code]

Dim count as Integer = 0
While (FileExists(file))
    count = count + 1
    file = dir & filename & count & extension
End While
```

It will exit the loop as soon as it finds an available name